# How Can I center this form inside my Footer using CSS?

Tags: html, css, forms

I have a stacked list and a form inside my footer and i want the list to be floated left and I want the Form to be in the center of the page how can I do this inside my css file?

```css
footer a {
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
  display: block;
}

form {
  float: center;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">Where To stay</a>
  <a href="#">Transportation</a>
  <a href="#">Island Activities</a>
  <a href="#">FAQ</a>

  <form>
    Email Newsletter:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="Email" Value="">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up">
  </form>
</footer>
```

Comment: There is no such thing as `float: center`

Comment: would text-align:center work?

Comment: " to be floated left and I want the Form to be in the center of the page" - so which one? Center of the screen is one place, so where do you want it? Horizontal center, vertical center?

Comment: I want the list to stay to the left side of the footer while the form is in the center of the footer

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try this way. Hope this works for you.

```css
.footer-list {
  margin-bottom: 18px;
  width: 35%;
  float: left;
}

.footer-form {
  width: 65%;
  margin-left: 15%;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

form {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="footer-list">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Where To stay</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Transportation</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Island Activities</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-form">
    <form>
      Email Newsletter:
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="Email" Value="">
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Sign Up">
    </form>
  </div>

</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

first, you should put the list inside another div :

```
<footer>
<div class="list">
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">Where To stay</a>
  <a href="#">Transportation</a>
  <a href="#">Island Activities</a>
  <a href="#">FAQ</a>
</div>

<form>
 Email Newsletter:
 <br>
 <input type="text" name="Email" Value="">
 <br>
 <input type="submit" value="Sign Up">
 </form>
</footer>
```

then make the width of the footer 100% :

```
footer { width: 100%; }
```

then position them :

```
.list { display: inline-block;
        float:left;}
form {margin:0 auto;}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a CSS property called [text-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align). You could be using this to align text to the center of a page.

Try to add the following code to your snippet `text-align: center;`. In order to make the form appear in-line with the list, I think the best way in order to achieve this you could be using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Try to add `display: flex;` to your footer:

```css
footer a {
  /*margin-left: 100px; /*<-- When using flexbox and using justify-content, you might not be needing this*/
  margin-bottom: 18px;
  display: block;
}

form#center {
  text-align: center;
}

footer#flex {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<footer id="flex">
  <div>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Where To stay</a>
    <a href="#">Transportation</a>
    <a href="#">Island Activities</a>
    <a href="#">FAQ</a>
  </div>

  <form id="center">
    Email Newsletter:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="Email" Value="">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up">
  </form>
</footer>
```

There are many other different methods to center elements as well (such as the `margin-left: auto;` + `margin-right: auto;` technique):

```css
footer a {
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
  display: block;
}

form#center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 175px; /*<-- requires a fixed width though*/
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">Where To stay</a>
  <a href="#">Transportation</a>
  <a href="#">Island Activities</a>
  <a href="#">FAQ</a>

  <form id="center">
    Email Newsletter:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="Email" Value="">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up">
  </form>
</footer>
```

Comment: Okay now it is putting the Form in the Center so it is working but it is under the list the I have is there a way to not have it under the list but level with it?

Comment: @DathonWeber Yes, there are multiple ways of doing this. I made an edit to this answer by making use of `display: flex;`. Please see my answer for more details.

Comment: @DathonWeber Glad to see it works, please upvote and leave a mark so that everyone could see that this answer might help others too.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```css
/* Try this*/

footer{
text-align:center;
border: 1px solid #80808017;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">Where To stay</a>
  <a href="#">Transportation</a>
  <a href="#">Island Activities</a>
  <a href="#">FAQ</a>

  <form>
    Email Newsletter:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="Email" Value="">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up">
  </form>
</footer>
```